# JSON SCHEMA: Can we do an either/or (string/int) for type?

Tags: json, types, jsonschema

I'm doing a schema to validate contact information.
In the phone number validation, we have a country code.
I am really hoping there's a way to allow the country code to either be a `string` or an `integer`.

Users from different countries inform me that there are sometimes meaningful non-integer characters in the country code (such as a "+"). That being said, a string makes sense.
On the other hand, if someone provides a country code as an int, say .. something like `33` (france), I feel it'd be a bit ridiculous, almost pretentious, to throw a failure alert and force them to cast it as a string and re-send it as `"33"`.

I would like to enforce type constraints to ensure that someone does not try to send an object or array, but I need to allow it to be one of either a `string` or an `integer`.
How can this be done?

Comment: Thinking about it from the opposite direction, is there maybe some way to just exclude the types I do not want rather than including the ones I do?

Comment: Are you talking about phone numbers or addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options, please have a [look at the docs](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#anchor88):

- Use pattern property, and use a regular expression to enforce valid code.
- Use anyOf with two schemas. Each schema will validate integer or string type.
- If you have all country codes (very easy to get) you might enforce exact values with an enum list.

Comment: I hadn't thought of your first or last suggestions (I was hoping to avoid the clutter of duplicating this _kinda_ large schema for such a single simple thing. Thanks-a-bunch. I'll prob go with a).

Answer (score 13):

You can validate multiple types using :

```
"type": ["integer", "string"]
```

More info: https://cswr.github.io/JsonSchema/spec/multiple_types/

Comment: This worked great for me. The resource you shared is very helpful too. The {} one also works!