# how to define alternative structure in json schema

Tags: javascript, json, jsonschema

I've got JSON files that can look either like this:

```
{
    "api": "http://my.api.host",
    "modules": [
        "core", "module", "another"
    ]
}
```

or this:

```
{
    "api": "http://my.api.host",
    "modules": "*"
}
```

Note that `modules` attribute can have either an array as its value or a `*` string. How can I do that in JSON schema? Using priceless http://jsonschema.net/ I have created following structure that validates arrays only:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "id": "http://jsonschema.net",
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties": true,
  "properties": {
    "api": {
      "id": "http://jsonschema.net/api",
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1
    },
    "modules": {
      "id": "http://jsonschema.net/modules",
      "type": "array",
      "minItems": 1,
      "uniqueItems": false,
      "additionalItems": true,
      "items": {
        "id": "http://jsonschema.net/modules/2",
        "type": "string",
        "minLength": 1
      }
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "api",
    "modules"
  ]
}
```

How can I make an alternative in JSON schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the answer, basing on another (slightly different) [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20886599/json-schema-can-we-do-an-either-or-string-int-for-type). The solution is to use [`anyOf`](http://jsonary.com/documentation/json-schema/?section=keywords/General%20keywords#keywords/General%20keywords/04%20-%20anyOf) which enables to define alternative subschemas where at least one has to match. An example solution for my case is:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "id": "http://jsonschema.net",
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties": true,
  "properties": {
    "api": {
      "id": "http://jsonschema.net/api",
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1
    },
    "modules": {
      "id": "http://jsonschema.net/modules",
      "anyOf": [{
        "type": "array",
        "minItems": 1,
        "uniqueItems": true,
        "items": {
          "id": "http://jsonschema.net/modules/2",
          "type": "string",
          "minLength": 1
        }
      }, {
        "type": "string",
        "minLength": 1
      }]
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "api",
    "modules"
  ]
}
```